# Mongodb: Unable to remove array elements using $pull in MongoDB updateMany

Tags: mongodb

Suppose i have a mongodb document like this

```js
{
  "_id": ObjectId("65956d418e914c17aa2d0593"),
  "admission_id": 4500331,
  "quiz": [{
    "id": 11512,
    "started_at": null,
    "completed_at": null
  }]
}
```

There can be many such documents with diff admission_id. I have a admission_id array and a quiz id array. For every document which match an element in admission_id array, i want to check if it has a matching doc from quiz id array in its quiz array. If it exists, remove THAT quiz doc from the array.
This is the query i am using

```js
db.collection.updateMany({
  "admission_id": {
    $in: [4500331, /*...more such ids*/ ]
  }
}, {
  $pull: {
    "quiz": {
      "id": {
        $in: [9486, 9232, 9491, 9500, 9003, 9391, 9011, 6837, 12086, 12089, 12090, 11512, 9410, 4933, 4934, 6866, 4955, 11505, 9080, 8700]
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  multi: true
})
```

When i execute this, i get

```js
{
  "acknowledged": true,
  "matchedCount": 0,
  "modifiedCount": 0
}
```

Even though the document with `"admission_id" : 4500331` has a doc in its quiz array with `"id" : 11512`, it doesn't remove it. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `matchedCount==0` means that no documents match the filter. Maybe check the filter first using `find` and build the update after the filter works.

Comment: @Markus did that already. It returned the mentioned document. Query `db.collection.find({"admission_id" : 4500331,"quiz.id":{$in: [9486, 9232, 9491, 9500, 9003, 9391, 9011, 6837, 12086, 12089, 12090, 11512, 9410, 4933, 4934, 6866, 4955, 11505, 9080, 8700]}})`

Comment: [Your attempt](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KF7dJXxl0GJ) seems working fine

Comment: @ray there is an index on admission_id and quiz id. Will it work if there are more than one docs with same admission_id (but diff elements in quiz array in each doc)? No duplicate_key exception?